# DataFrame: query column if it has negative and positve values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a very large dataframe with meterId retailPrice. I want to output only the meterIds when there are both positive and 0 values. My current query is very performance heavy and I could not check the correctness yet.

Is there a more performant way?

```
d = {'meterId': ["x", "x", "y", "y", "z", "z"], 'retailPrice': [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

[image]

```
tmp = pd.DataFrame(df["meterId"])
for x in tmp["meterId"]:`
    zero_values = pd.DataFrame(df.loc[(df['meterId'] == x) & df['retailPrice'] == 0)])
    positive_values = pd.DataFrame(df.loc[(df['meterId'] == x) & (df['retailPrice'] > 0)])
    if not zero_values.empty and not positive_values.empty:
        print("meterID: " + str(x))
```

My output should be like this:
`"meterID: x"`

Comment: I dont get it, why is column z not a wanted index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
In [113]: pos = df.retailPrice >  0

In [114]: zer = df.retailPrice == 0

In [115]: pos.groupby(df.meterId).any() & zer.groupby(df.meterId).any()
Out[115]:
meterId
x     True
y    False
z    False
Name: retailPrice, dtype: bool

In [116]: _[_].index.tolist()
Out[116]: ['x']
```

- get whether `pos`itive or not mask
- get whether `zer`o or not mask
- group these mask by ID and check if `any` value satisfies them
- since need *both* pos and zero, `&` them; gives a True/False series for IDs as the desired result
- index it with itself to retain only where True and get the index

`_` is the last evaled thing, so i refer to the previous output with it. you can do `s = ...` in 115 and do `s[s].index.tolist()`

Comment: Should be `pos = df.retailPrice > 0` otherwise it doesn't work. But nice answer :)

Comment: thanks a lot @JoshFriedlander, yours is too. (i used `.gt` first, then some users don't like it so much, but then i went back to a bad thing...)

Answer (score 2):

This also works:

```
for id_, group in df.groupby(['meterId'])['retailPrice']:
    if (group==0).any() & (group>0).any():
        print(f"meter id: {id_}")
```

But [Mustafa Aydın's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73776647/6220759) is more elegant.

Comment: you can do `for id_, sub_df in df.groupby("meterID"):`. Then, you're able to remove `df.meterID == ` checks while doing `sub_df.retailPrice ...`. Or even `["retailPrice"]` after groupby since that's the only column of interest in the for's suite...

Comment: That's great - I've adjusted my answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

here is another way , using `group by` , let us know which approach was more performant :

```
res = df.groupby('meterId')['retailPrice'].apply(lambda x: (x > 0).sum() > 0 and (x == 0).sum() > 0)
out = res[res].index.tolist()
```

Comment: There is no significant difference between your and [Mustafa Aydın's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73776647/6220759) does in terms of performance for my use case. But thanks for your approach!

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
#df
    meterId retailPrice
0   x       1
1   x       0
2   y       0
3   y       0
4   z       1
5   z       1

zero_values_condition      = df['meterId'].eq('x') & df['retailPrice'].eq(0) #eq() means ==
positive_values_condition  = df['meterId'].eq('x') & df['retailPrice'].gt(0) #gt() means >
df['new_col'] = np.where((zero_values_condition|positive_values_condition), "meterID: x", '')

df
    meterId retailPrice new_col
0   x       1           meterID: x
1   x       0           meterID: x
2   y       0   
3   y       0   
4   z       1   
5   z       1
```